# This condition will always return true when comparing `!==`

Tags: typescript

I am puzzled by this error. I have an `enum` and a `type`

```js
 enum EventName {
  None = 'None',
  Delete = 'Delete',
  Add = 'Add'
}

 type EventObject = {
  name: Exclude<EventName, EventName.None>,
  id: number,
} | {
  name: EventName.None
};
```

comparing an `EventObject` variable to `Add` or `Delete` infers correctly that I have an `id``
[image: I have an Id]

But trying to do that with none fails with:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'EventName.Delete | EventName.Add' and 'EventName.None' have no overlap.

I have not found how to map that correctly.

Here [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwdgrgtsCiBu4AuA5AhlEwDeBYAUMMCgPZhYC8wA5KedQDQFEAiIANiEpTW5942bAAggBNRwKtTGjqBAL4FmSAJ4AHLAmQB5AEYArEAGMkknELAYQALjgAPI%20wiiQAHi1hUVhnESf0mAB0dCAAfEyEwACWoraQULogAE4R8sAAPuaRlpi2Hl5BIQoA3Er4RmQAzqZ2eX5IeoYmZnjZVnXIASCBfFwgEUQxtgCMJWUEUQBmwAAUdoE5lBRU%20V2BMgCUrURE81EK4-hTcwtWksu%20nVbBZCBbQrsH%20IdTs-OLwACEF6vXIRtZXaBJ5AA)

Comment: Looks like a problem with typecasting. You can compare it as `<string>x.name === EventName.None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of errors typically happen if you declare a `const` of a full type with a value of a narrower type. For example:

```
const x: EventObject = { name: EventName.None }
```

Despite having a type signature of `EventObject`, the actual type of `x` gets narrowed to `{ name: EventName.None }`, which explains the error.

```
type Tx = typeof x // type is not EventObject but narrowed to { name: EventName.None }
type Txname = typeof x.name // type is EventName.None

if (x.name === EventName.Add) {
  // ERROR: .. 'EventName.None' and 'EventName.Add' have no overlap.
}
```

To test with an `x` of type `EventObject` you can declare it as a function parameter:

```
const test = (x: EventObject) => {
  type Tx = typeof x // type is EventObject
  type Txname = typeof x.name // type is EventName

  if (x.name === EventName.Add) {
    type Txname2 = typeof x.name // type is EventName.Add
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're not executing the code, you can just use `{} as any` for the `const` value:

```
const y: EventObject = {} as any

type Ty = typeof y // type is EventObject
type Tyname = typeof y.name // type is EventName

if (y.name === EventName.Add) {
  type Txname2 = typeof x.name // type is EventName.Add
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgOQIYWFA3gWAFBRTID2ImAvFAOQllUA0%20hAIsADbCIXWsdcNMoAQQAmIqJSqiRVfAF98TRAE8ADpnhIA8gCMAVsADGiCdkEh0wAFywAHobZgRwADyaQKS-VgIPaDAB0tMAAfIwEUACWIjbgEDrAAE7hclAAPmYRFhg27p6BwfIA3Ip4hqQAzia2ub6IugbGplhQ2dY%20SP7AQaSYCnj4KupQACq2pkPAxABmUOMA9PNQk1EVrcQmeQ1GJjpgJhaJicQA7sDiiMTYrZa1nZY9ZFD9K2NtE2pTs7YB74vLn1WHT8D0KAzwkVmAAofu9yPDgflutIAJSZQj-GAAJSxWixNgCAWoeS6j2AVCgqBA4ioJIe0gpAAtUAh1lBiAhEmxUKoAvJSuUQFUoMo7h5tk1KFhUqg1lTlKVXsoPuoZiKoP8VpE1lt9DtBoCRso4QDVbNlL9LBqllqdXUuqVIVAoRa4Qi6YFUejTZg3pYAEwqr5zS0Ya0%20oEe5FifngwXCrjCygwsX1PXGNHkELe17jSiTNULG2A7WIiWIQS5k0F76hzCakt2%204YUqEJ0wusSd32%20liNG4CKEKsBoOFzsN4alqMBaSCfr9IA)